# How to use a python trained model in your seperate python script

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I am quite new to deep learning and machine leanring. So i have this model trained with tensorflow on google Colab. It recognizes gestures on model.predict() function and prints the result. I downloaded this .h5 file. Now my question is how do i use this model (or the .h5 file)in my python script where i want to make predictions.

i am using https://colab.research.google.com/github/lmoroney/dlaicourse/blob/master/Course%202%20-%20Part%208%20-%20Lesson%202%20-%20Notebook%20(RockPaperScissors).ipynb

I just want to ask how can i lets say IMPORT this mosel into my python code, How do we actually use a trained model in our programs?

Comment: Please [edit] to include a [mcve] including _code_ for what you've already tried based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts

Comment: @G.Anderson i just want to ask how do we import a trained model into our own program. So lets say i have a trained model which classifies dogs and cats. If I want to use this classifier in my python program to detect on runtime, how do i do that.Kindly help and thanks for replying

Comment: Wouldn't this kind of information be found in the documentation for whatever framework/library you're using? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to load the .h5 file if it's in the same directory as the script from which the file is being loaded:

```
from keras.models import load_model
import os
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
model = load_model(os.path.join(dirname, 'name_of_file.h5'))
```

What `os.path.join(directory_name, 'name_of_file.h5')` gives you is something like `C:\...\name_of_file.h5`, i.e. the path from which the model is loaded.

Then just do `model.predict(x)` where needed.

If the script and the .h5 file are not in the same directory, then just tweak the `dirname`.

Comment: thanks alot, i was just trying this for a week now.

Comment: You're welcome! Please upvote my answer if you found it useful. :)